# Issue with Facebook links in Android WebviewFragment ERR_UKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook

I've started to have an issue with a WebviewFragment which opens inside my Android app which is meant to open a Facebook Page within the webview, this was working until recently (can't say exactly when), but now when you click on the icon that opens the webview, it correctly opens the Facebook page in the webview, but then immediately jumps to a Google error page which says `"Webpage not available, the webpage at fb://page/xxxxxxxxx could not be loaded because: net:ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME"`

The `webviewFragment` code within the Android app loads a URL that contains a `meta-equiv="refresh"` code that forwards onto the actual Facebook page URL.

I'm certain the `webviewFragment` is working correctly because it loads other pages (Twitter Page) correctly without giving this error.

From the `fb://` link error it seems to be loading the Facebook Page URL and then trying to open the Facebook app by converting it to an internal Facebook link (`fb://`) to tell it to load it within the FB App?

My preference to try and resolve this would definitely be to do something within the link rather than having to update the app, but I'm not entirely sure what changed and what is happening.

To clarify, the Android app calls a URL on our site (domain.com/facebok.html) and within that page we perform a meta-equiv refresh to the actual Facebook Pages URL.

Any thoughts on how I can resolve this?

UPDATE :

- `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` is definitely in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
- The Facebook App is installed on the device, but we're expecting it to load the Facebook Page within the WebView (as a web page), not open the Facebook App.
- The app code has not changed at all, this seems a change of behaviour potentially due to the operating system update which has made this behaviour change.

Comment: Could this be a bug with the facebook page in early to mid January 2023 that has since been fixed? As I noticed it before, then when I went back to troubleshoot in late January, the problem was not happening.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I wasn't aware of the bug, but I've since checked again and the issue is still present.

Answer (score 1):

I used this and it works for me.

```
override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                    view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?
                ): Boolean {
                    val url = request?.url.toString()

                    if (url.startsWith("fb://")) {
                        // Open Facebook app using intent
                        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
                        try {
                            startActivity(intent)
                        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                            // Facebook app is not installed, handle the error or fallback to a web-based solution
                            Toast.makeText(
                                context, "Facebook app not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }
                        return true
                    }

                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is still there with Facebook URL Scheme I guess.

As recently I was working on something similar and I have to open a Facebook Page from my Android App. This same things was happening with me as well.

I took a search around the Internet and I found the similar answers posted by @ikmazameti but I didn't like the redirection flow.

when I not satisfied with any resolution.

I just tried with a very simple resolution that We should tell `Webview` about this  `Facebook` Internal `URL Scheme` `"fb://"` that You should load this right there in the same page.

For that, I have used this piece of code and It's working for me everywhere.

> In your `Webview Client`, You should paste this code inside this method

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
      String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
      if (url == null) {
          return true;
      }
      if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(host) && url.startsWith("fb://") && host.contains("profile")) {
          return true;
      } else {
          view.loadUrl(url);
      }
      return true;
}
```

Comment: perfectly working!